# Change User Permissions from windows to a shared folder by OpenIndiana

Tags: permissions, windows, openindiana

I have a problem with OpenIndiana, I am migrating a server that works with Napp-It. But, once migrated the Hipster Realease Napp-it not support that OS.

I am trying to find out how can I do by console the same that Nappit when I add a user and add properties inherit, in `Modify_set`.

I have in this moment my ACL like this:

```
root@openindiana:~# zfs list -H -o aclmode videopool/data
passthrough
root@openindiana:~# zfs list -H -o aclinherit /videopool/data/
passthrough
root@openindiana:~# zfs get aclinherit /videopool/data/
NAME            PROPERTY    VALUE          SOURCE
videopool/data  aclinherit  passthrough    local
```

But, When I go to my Windows Sever, I connect the shared folder like a disk, and I try to change the user permissions, but instead of see the 2 users like in my OI old version with Napp-it  (Root and User1) 
I see (Current Owner and everyone). Or, I see numbers like

```
(S-1-5-21-285024196-2039105400-3618605989-1101)
```

In both cases when I try to change the permissions the Explorer.exe close automatically.

[image: 3 times]

I attach the screenshots

[image: I want to do]